# How to generate feed for Feed Me plugin

Tags: craft3, plugin-feedme, feed

I have a site in staging and production env, they have the same data structure. I want to sync an entry from staging to production. Is it something that Feed Me plugin can do? and how to generate the feed from staging, then import into production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feed Me could do this, yes.

Feed Me can accept the following formats:

- JSON
- CSV
- XML
- Google Sheet

Your best bet is to use JSON and have it created via an [Element API](https://plugins.craftcms.com/element-api), which is a first-party plugin.

You can follow the documentation to get a basic endpoint up and running without too much effort. It does require some familiarity with PHP but for basic usage, you can probably get away with using the [example code provided in the documentation - scroll down in the docs to see example usages](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api#setup).

With the Element API, you will expose the elements as JSON. They will be available at a URL you specify via the endpoint (e.g. `yoursite.com/api/news.json`). This is the URL you input into Feed Me, map the fields, etc. If everything is set up correctly, Feed Me will parse the JSON and import it.